# Convert pandas dataframe to dict of list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to convert a 3 column pandas dataframe to something like `{key:[{},{},{}]}`

However I am really not able to figure it out.

**Sample Data:**

```
            0    1         2
0  2019-01-21  BBB  11101110
1  2019-01-21  CCC  11101010
2  2019-01-21  DDD  10101110
3  2019-01-20  BBB  11101110
4  2019-01-20  CCC  11101010
5  2019-01-20  DDD  10101110
```

**Expected Data:**

```
[
    {'BBB': [{'2019-01-21': '11101110'}, {'2019-01-20': '11101110'}]}, 
    {'CCC': [{'2019-01-21': '11101010'}, {'2019-01-20': '11101010'}]}, 
    {'DDD': [{'2019-01-21': '10101110'}, {'2019-01-20': '10101110'}]}
]
```

I tried, following things, however it's not working.

```
a = dict(zip(df[1], [dict(zip(df[0], df[2]))]))
print(a)
{'BBB': {'2019-01-21': '10101110', '2019-01-20': '10101110'}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`dict & list comprehension`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)

```
[{_: [{k:v for k, v in zip(g['0'], g['2'])}] for _, g in df.groupby('1')}]
```

Which outputs `dict`s together

```
[{'BBB': [{'2019-01-21': 11101110, '2019-01-20': 11101110}],
  'CCC': [{'2019-01-21': 11101010, '2019-01-20': 11101010}],
  'DDD': [{'2019-01-21': 10101110, '2019-01-20': 10101110}]}]
```

Or

```
[{_: [{k:v} for k, v in zip(g['0'], g['2'])]} for _, g in df.groupby('1')]
```

Which outputs separate `dict`s

```
[{'BBB': [{'2019-01-21': 11101110}, {'2019-01-20': 11101110}]},
 {'CCC': [{'2019-01-21': 11101010}, {'2019-01-20': 11101010}]},
 {'DDD': [{'2019-01-21': 10101110}, {'2019-01-20': 10101110}]}]
```

---

Comprehensions work just like regular `for` loops, but with some advantages such as (i) the process *'hides'* intermediate temporary variables in the loops, (ii) it usually requires less lines of code than the expanded `for` loops, and (iii) most importantly, there are several benefits on performance, since comprehensions use underlying C code behind the scenes, and makes it unnecessary to perform several lookups related to those *hidden* variables that I mentioned (e.g. looking up `append`, `__getitem__` etc takes considerable additional time).

The expanded loop would look something like this:

```
final_list = []
for _, g in df.groupby('1'):
    intermediate_list = []
    intermediate_dict = {_:intermediate_list}
    for k,v in zip(g['0'], g['2']):
        intermediate_list.append({k:v})
    final_list.append(intermediate_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

```
df['New']=[{x : y} for x,y in zip(df['0'], df['2'])]
df
            0    1         2                       New
0  2019-01-21  BBB  11101110  {'2019-01-21': 11101110}
1  2019-01-21  CCC  11101010  {'2019-01-21': 11101010}
2  2019-01-21  DDD  10101110  {'2019-01-21': 10101110}
3  2019-01-20  BBB  11101110  {'2019-01-20': 11101110}
4  2019-01-20  CCC  11101010  {'2019-01-20': 11101010}
5  2019-01-20  DDD  10101110  {'2019-01-20': 10101110}


d=df.groupby('1').New.apply(list).to_dict()
d
{'BBB': [{'2019-01-21': 11101110}, {'2019-01-20': 11101110}], 
 'CCC': [{'2019-01-21': 11101010}, {'2019-01-20': 11101010}], 
 'DDD': [{'2019-01-21': 10101110}, {'2019-01-20': 10101110}]}
```

---

If you want list of dict

```
d=[{k: v} for (k, v) in d.items()()]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for row in df.to_dict('records'):
    d[row.get('1')].append({row.get('0'): row.get('2')})

defaultdict(list,
            {'BBB': [{'2019-01-21': 11101110}, {'2019-01-20': 11101110}],
             'CCC': [{'2019-01-21': 11101010}, {'2019-01-20': 11101010}],
             'DDD': [{'2019-01-21': 10101110}, {'2019-01-20': 10101110}]})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.pivot('0','1','2').groupby(level=0,axis=1).apply(lambda dd:dd.to_dict()).tolist()
```

or

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    dd1=dd.drop('1',axis=1).set_index("0").set_axis([dd.name],axis=1)
    return dd1.to_dict()

df1.groupby('1').apply(function1).squeeze().tolist()
```

output：

```
[{'BBB': {'2019-01-21': 11101110, '2019-01-20': 11101110}},
 {'CCC': {'2019-01-21': 11101010, '2019-01-20': 11101010}},
 {'DDD': {'2019-01-21': 10101110, '2019-01-20': 10101110}}]
```